# Eureka Get Dictionary Values Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type, eureka-forms

I am using the Eureka form library found [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka). I am trying to iterate over the dictionary values of the form and only print the values that are true; not nil or not false. So far I have

```
     let valuesDictionary = form.values()

        for (_, version) in valuesDictionary
        {

            if version != nil || version as! Bool != false // error here

            {
                print (version!)
            }

        }
```

I am getting the following error on the if statement:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
for (_, version) in valuesDictionary
{
    if let version = version, version as? Bool != false {
        print(version)
    } 
}
```

This will translated as:

- `if let version = version`: if there is a value (`version is not nil`)

After checking if it's not null (*optional binding*), as a *where* condition:

- `version as? Bool != false`: checks tow points:

1- is `version` could be cast to `Bool`.

2- If the first point is true, check if version is not `false`.